# Is in_memory reused by multiple geoprocessing services (ArcGIS Server)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing-service

I have a GP service published on ArcGIS Server 10.2.2. This GP service is going to be used by multiple users at the same time and for intermediate data storage I use [in_memory](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000005s000000) workspace.

I was not able to find on the Internet though whether the datasets I save in in_memory in one GP service session will be "visible" in another one, and thus result in lock issues when trying to overwrite an existing dataset or delete a dataset that is currently being used by another GP service session.

I am hoping for having in_memory encapsulated for each GP service run (session), but wanted to check if anyone knows for sure how it works with GP services.

I know that I can use [arcpy.env.scratchGDB](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000047000000) for the intermediate data storage in a file geodatabase (which will be unique for each GP service run), but it is way slower and since I have to write many times during the run, this will negatively affect the service performance.

The same question available [here on GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/93264) with no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output to the in_memory workspace is not available from one instance to another.
An instance is a process (ArcSOC.exe). These processes do not share memory, nor talk to one another.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin! Good to know. I asked this because I have gotten some locks established when running multiple GP service sessions of the same service. Then those locks were probably on the database level. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, you could still be getting locks on the database. That would have nothing to do with writing output to in_memory. It would be what tool(s) are being used and if they need to put a read or schema lock on the input features. (schema being the possible problematic lock depending what you're doing)